# Filling an image to a column such that it shows till just the first page

Tags: html, css, deployment

Using bootstrap, I made a div with 2 columns with 0 gutters and put an image in the second column. It's actually talking complete full height of the image. I tried it to fit up to the first page only by using css properties such as object-fit, bacground-size, etc but not able to do so

This is what I've tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" />
  </head>

    <title>My Lead Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <div class="">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 justify-content-center">Column-1</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 second-column">
           <img src="project.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: class="img-fluid" try  this class in img tag

Comment: Actually, the image is vertical and this is not fitting the image just up to the first page

Answer (score 0):

you can target the second column image and add a height of 100vh for the image to take up the full height of the viewport

```css
.second-column img {
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: This helped me, but actually the image is vertical and it is leaving some white space from both left and right. How do I fix that?

Comment: You can try adding either of the following to you ".second-column img" class

"width:100%;"

or

"object-position: center"

the width will stretch the image to fill but will distort the image.

With the object-position and object-fit, you can experiment with that by using these references:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position